# Not Terminating EOF with sshpass

Tags: linux, shell-script

Below is my script code:

```
sshpass -e ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" voltdb@$DB_SERVER_IP /bin/bash << EOF
cd voltdb/bin
echo "ReInitializing VoltDB, Wait for 5second"
./voltdb init --force
sleep 5s
echo "Starting VoltDB, Wait for 20second"
./voltdb start &
sleep 20s
echo "setUpVoltDB completed"
exit
EOF
echo "After EOF"
```

Here `./voltdb start &` is executed as a background process

When I run the whole script, it is executing all commands in `EOF` block but I never reach to `echo "After EOF"`

If I comment `./voltdb start & line` then all works fine.

Please guide me as to what changes are required to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

My tests indicate that when `bash` on the remote side gets `exit`, it waits for its job(s) to finish. This should change the behavior:

```
./voltdb start &
disown $!
```

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/108618) you'll be fine unless the process tries to read from standard input or write to standard output. In this case you may want to research `nohup` or `tmux` (or `screen`).